# Casting variables to the function

Tags: c, function, variables, casting

According to the standard of the C language, does the casting when passing to a function occur automatically in C? For example, can we give foo (int a, int b) values of type char a, b, or we should do so: foo ((int) a, (int) b).

Comment: Are you asking whether you can write `foo(a, b)` without writing the casts?

Comment: @M.M -  I had it reversed.  cast of `int` to `char` would generate warning. Thanks, have removed the comment.

Comment: @rsjaffe that question covers a different topic  (what happens when you pass arguments to an undeclared function)

Comment: Always do explicit casts instead of implicit ones. And turn on compiler warnings about implicit ones.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the standard of the C language, does the casting when
>   passing to a function occur automatically in C?

"Casting" is the application of a typecast operator, which has the form of a type name enclosed in parentheses.  The effect of such an operator, if it has one, is a *conversion* of the operand to the type specified by the operator.  Being the effect of an operator, a cast is never automatic.  Some other conversions are performed automatically, however, and I suppose that's what you mean.

> For example, can we
>   give foo (int a, int b) values of type char a, b, or we should do so:
>   foo ((int) a, (int) b).

You can use casts to convert the variables to the types of the function parameters, but in many cases, including your example case, it is not necessary to do so.  Provided that the function has an in-scope prototype and that the argument expressions satisfy [the same requirements as for simple assignment](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p1) with respect to the corresponding function parameters,  the argument expressions are converted automatically to the parameter types.  In particular, if the function parameters have any arithmetic type (as opposed to pointer, array, structure, or union type), then argument expressions of the same or any other arithmetic type may be used without a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the casting at a function call will be automatically done for you by the compiler will depend on the variable types used in the function call and the variable types available in the function definition for the compiler to make decisions about casting.

A C compiler will make intelligent automatic casting decisions if the variable types in the function call are the built in types (int, long, float, etc.) and if a declaration of the actual function interface is available.

The C compiler is also able to check the variable types used in a function call against the function definition if the function declaration is available. If the compiler detects problems then it will issue a warning or an error depending on the problem found.

If the function interface, the arguments used in the function definition, are not available to the C compiler at the place where the function call is being done then the C compiler can not do checking of the variable types used against the function definition nor can it do a proper job of automatically casting variable types to fit the actual function definition.

However the C compiler will assume that the first occurrence of the use of a function is the correct one, should there not be a function declaration, and will automatically generate a function declaration for you based on that first use.

There are rules in the C Standard about what the C compiler will do when it is performing automatic casting. So if the function declaration is for an `int` and you provide a `char` in the function call then the C compiler will automatically do the cast to `int` for you.

There are also some default, legacy rules that are grandfathered into the C Standard about assumptions of a function when it is used and there is no function declaration for the C compiler to use to check the function usage.

A function declaration is something like:

```
int func1 (int a, int b);   // declare the interface for function func1().
```

A function definition contains the actual code for the function implementation and is something like:

```
int func1 (int a, int b)
{
    if (a < 50) a = 0;
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: In C99 and later, it is a constraint violation to attempt to call an undeclared function.  Conforming compilers will at minimum emit a diagnostic.  Those that accept such calls anyway -- for compatibility with legacy code, for example -- have no requirements at all on how they handle them, though in practice they are likely to behave more or less as described here.